# LINQ to XML, get unique node in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have an XML file that represents a list of books that the user has access to.

```
<Book Bookid="1" BookName="Book1" />
<Book Bookid="1" BookName="Book1" />
<Book Bookid="2" BookName="Book2" />
<Book Bookid="1" BookName="Book1" />
```

That is in an XElement named xBooks

I am trying to get each book in the XML once.

```
Dim DistinctBooks = (From item In xBooks.Elements("Book") Select item).Distinct()
```

That line doesn't seem to do anything, the value of DistinctBooks is the same as xBooks.

I have searched for the solution, but it seems everyone that is doing LINQ is doing it in C#. Even though i've found other posts in C# that should work, i'm either not translating from C# to VB correctly, or VB does things differently. can anyone bump me in the right direction to get this to work in VB?

Thanks!

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is declared:

```
Dim xBooks = <books>
               <Book Bookid="1" BookName="Book1"/>
               <Book Bookid="1" BookName="Book1"/>
               <Book Bookid="2" BookName="Book2"/>
               <Book Bookid="1" BookName="Book1"/>
             </books>
```

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Dim DistinctBooks = From item In xBooks.Elements("Book")
                    Select bookid = item.Attribute("Bookid").Value,
                           bookName = item.Attribute("BookName").Value
                    Distinct
```

Why it did not work for you is because every node is different if you consider a set of all properties that it implements. With the above you tell it which properties you need as part of a unique key for distinct. Also notice there is no need to combine multiple styles of LINQ (query and functional), you can use word `Distinct` as part of the query.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I added the other attributes and children nodes that i had stripped for testing purposes back to the XML and also to the select, and it still works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Neolisk's correct answer, with VB you might want to consider using the more concise syntax:

```
Dim DistinctBooks = From item In xBooks.<Book>
                    Select bookid = item.@Bookid,
                           bookName = item.@BookName
                    Distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

A few years late to this thread.. but

I believe he is asking for the '**lamba**' expression instead of the '**sql**' expression.

I got this LINQ Lambda expression to work with my VB.NET project just now: (windows 7, vs15)

```
Dim myxdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xdocfilepath)
Dim newlist = myxdoc.Root.Descendants.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Name).Select(Function(x) x.First).Where(Function(x) x.Name = "partNumber").ToList

For Each item In newlist
     Debug.Print(item.Value.ToString())
Next
```